# Telegram On Desktop does not record all keyboard strikes and is extremelly laggy

Tags: telegram

I have installed [Telegram Desktop](https://desktop.telegram.org/) on Kubuntu 16.04. I installed the application directly from the site (not through apt).

Any ideas on troubleshooting this? Or is this normal.

PS:

1. When I use the desktop app, I am simultaneously logged in with 3 instances.
2. Writing a long text in e.g. Kate and copying it into the Desktop application is no problem.

**EDIT:**
The above happens only when telegram starts automatically after boot (I have enabled System Settings --> Desktop Session --> On login Restore previous session. If I quit telegram and restart it, it works fine. Starting from command line returns only some minor fontconfig warnings.

```
.
```

Comment: This is not normal (it works like a charme for me). Can you monitor its CPU/Memory usage via `top`? If you launch it from terminal, does it give you any error?

Comment: Definitely something wrong. This doesn't help and it's just FYI: The version available in the repositories is the same. Prefer the official packages from the official repository whenever doable, like this particular software.

Comment: @dadexix86 Thank you for leading me to kill the process once in between (should really have done this before posting). The problem occurs only directly after boot (but it persists). So my workaround for the time being will be to start telegram manually and to change my Desktop Session Settings to "On Login Start with an empty Session".